# RSpec + Paperclip: identify: no decode delegate for this image format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, imagemagick, paperclip

I am trying to run my RSpec tests and I keep getting this error when the paperclip tests are ran:

```
identify: no decode delegate for this image format `0x000001034f6718>' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/532.
```

I am using Rails 3.2, latest version of ImageMagick and the jpeg libraries are installed...

Answer (score 1):

you need to install libjpeg, libpng libraries in the system. you can do this by searching 'jibjpeg' inside Ubuntu Software Center app.

then install [imagemagik from source](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue on a Mac (El captain) this solution helped me:

1. In your command line

   ```
   gem unistall rmagick
   ```

if you have more then one version installed choose both.
Now you have no 'gem rmagick' installed.

2. In your command line

   ```
   brew install imagemagick
   ```

You might get notification that you need overwrite already existing files
then just run:

```
   brew install imagemagick --dry-run
```

3. Edit your Gemfile and put your desired rmagick version like this.

   *gem 'rmagick', '2.15,4'* Save it.
4. In your command line

   ```
   bundle
   ```

Hope this helps, good luck!